# Normalized Vertex to Cartesian

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, cartesian

Currently, I am using DirectX 11 to draw a primitive on my screen.
Currently the Vertex is in normalized coordinates where the position ranges from -1, -1 to 1, 1.

I would like to set up my Vertex to use Cartesian coordinates 0, 800 to 0, 600.
Indeed I am aware that I can convert it manually, but I would rather set it up to work automatically. Similar to glOrtho in OpenGL where you pass the screen resolution to use Cartesian coordinates instead.

What calculation can I do on my view port or what function can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: `glOrtho` is deprecated in newer versions of OpenGL; doing it "manually" (or, more likely, getting a math library like GLM) and using shaders is the only option. I suspect it's similar in DirectX.

Comment: Do you really need these values in the vertex shader?  By default, the normalized coordinates are automatically converted to viewport-based coordinates (e.g. 800x600) when output from the vertex shader.  Also, the Cartesian property of the coordinates is unrelated to their scale - both normalized and viewport-space coordinates are Cartesian.